# Segment connected lines(with thickness)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a data analysis project. Basically, it is like multiple lines connected at one end. I need to find an algorithm or machine learning model to segment those lines. An example is attached below. I want to segment lines in the first plot to be the ones showing in the second plot.  Please notice that lines have thickness.

Original Plot:

[image: Original Plot]

Segmented one:

[image: Segmented one]

Answer (score 0):

I assume those lines consists of a lot of 2D points respectively pixels. You can apply a line fitting based on [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).

It basically randomly chooses two points connects them to a line and tests how many points are supporting this hypothesis (how many points are nearby this line). These steps are repeated many times and the line with the highest number of inliers "wins". Therefore, you need to apply it three times for three lines. **EDIT: After detecting one line, just remove the inliers and re-run everything.**

Make sure to define the threshold which distinct between inlier and outlier at most as the half of the line thickness and that the line normal distance is used. You also can try to decrease the threshold just for line fitting and then use the half thickness for segmentation.

As an alternative you can try [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html).

Comment: You are right, they are a lot of 2D points. I tried RANSAC and hough transform. RANSAC is for single line and hough transform needs 1-pixel width straight lines. Neither algorithms work in my attempts. Maybe I am not doing it correctly. It will be helpful, if you can show me a working code.

Comment: As already mentioned, you can apply RANSAC multiple times. First time it will find the line with most points, then you can remove the inliers and repeat it to get the remaining lines. The method HoughLines in the second link (including an example) has two resolution parameters, the higher those values the more tolerant is the line detection. You need to tune them to obtain a proper result. I don't have your data, so I can't provide working code and actually this is not how stackoverflow works (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: I tried RANSAC and I know how RANSAC and Houghtransform work, but apparently neither of the solution solves the problem. Let me upload the data and also the results first.